How to Isolate a Common Biopotential Signal from Dual Sensor Readings with Different Motion Artifacts?
I am a beginner in signal processing and working on a problem involving a dual biopotential (ECG) sensor setup. One sensor uses dry galvanic contact, and the other uses capacitive non-contact sensing. These sensors pick up signals from the same site. To understand the problem, let's have a look at two states: resting and motion.

Resting State: Both channels provide similar output in the absence of motion artifacts ($y_{1} \approx y_{2} = x$) as shown in figure 1.
Motion State: Both channels experience different types of motion artifacts (unequal in magnitude and shape), mixed with the biopotential data. ($y_{1} = x + n_{1}$ and $y_{2} = x + n_{2}$) as shown in figure 2.


The capacitive sensors are more prone and thereby exhibit larger amplitudes of motion artefacts as shown in figure 2.

Given two assumptions

Biopotential data $x$ is equal in both channels
noise $n_{1}$, $n_{2}$ are distinct.

The goal is to use dry ($y_{1}$) and capacitive ($y_{2}$) data to identify the common component $x$, which will represent the clean biopotential data.
What statistical or signal processing methods can be used to achieve this separation of $x$ from the noisy signals $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$? I'm interested in understanding the best approach or combination of approaches to isolate the clean biopotential signal or at least remove/reduce the noise $n_{2}$ from the dry signal. What kind of adaptive filtering can work on this kind of problem? What about signal decomposition techniques (PCA, ICA, EMD etc) ? What signal processing techniques should I explore more?


Both channels provide similar output in the absence of motion artifacts (y1 ~= y2 = x) as shown in figure [1].

That is clearly not true since the capacitive sensor shows a DC drift whereas the dry sensor has a constant DC bias. However, they could be easily made to look a lot closer by applying a DC blocker or high pass filter at very low frequency.
I think your first line of defense is do some spectral analysis: look at the spectra of the motion artifacts and desired signal and trim the spectrum to the "frequency range of interest". What are the frequencies you really need and what can you just cut off (signal and noise)?

The capacitive sensors are more prone and thereby exhibit larger amplitudes of motion artefacts

That's a bit of understatement. The noise at the capacitive sensor is at least 30dB larger than that on the dry sensor. The noise almost entirely obliterates the actual signal.

What statistical or signal processing methods can be used to achieve this separation of x from the noisy signals y1 and y2?

Given the massive amount of noise on the capacitive sensor I think your best shot here is to use the capacitive signal to create an estimate of the noise signal at the dry sensor and subtract it out. Specifically I assume here that both noise signals are caused by the same motion and that that the conversion of motion to noise is (more or less) linear and time invariant. This may or may not be the case (I don't know).
In this case we could write
$$y_c(t) = x(t) + m(t)*h_c(t), y_d(t) = x(t) + m(t)*h_d(t)$$
where $m(t)$ is the motion signal and $h_c(t)$ and $h_d(t)$ are the impulse responses of transfer functions of the motion signal to the capacitive and the dry sensor respectively. In the frequency domain we can write the recovery as
$$X(\omega) \approx Y_d(\omega) - \frac{H_d(\omega)}{H_c(\omega)}Y_c(\omega) $$
We are tryin to exploit the fact here that the noise is so much larger on the capacitive sensor, i.e.  $|\frac{H_d(\omega)}{H_c(\omega)}| \ll 1$
In order to do this, you would need to determine the ratio of the  motion to sensor transfer functions. Perhaps these can be measure directly using some well defined motion signals. If that doesn't work you could try an adaptive filter that minimizes $e(t) = y_d(t) - h_{adaptive}(t)*y_c(t)$ where you would need to control the adaption by the amount of noise present. I.e. only adapt when the noise level on $y_c(t)$ is reasonably large.
